# how to remove image refrences stored in numpy array as string based on some condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wanted to avoid using for loops so I switched to numpy array...

```
#SOURCE is the path where images are actually stored
content = np.array(os.listdir(SOURCE))

# content contains array of element type str_
```

I want to apply condition on content and get new arrays containing removed labels and not removed labels

```
condition: os.path.getsize(os.path.join(SOURCE, content)) > 0

# When I say content it means all the values in the content array
```

How can I implement this using vectorized approach ...

Comment: `content` contains a list of filename correct? Do you want to check the filesize greater than `0`. this condition would pass for all the files. Explain me more on your condition?

Comment: @NarendraPrasath yes content contains file names (files are all images). I know but my dataset contains files with 0 size  which I have to filter out before using !

Comment: I have given my solution, You can check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` for this.

#### Demonstrated how to filter from `list` and `numpy array` in below

```
import os
import numpy as np

SOURCE = "test"
```

Get the list of file using `os.listdir`

```
## files is list object
files =  os.listdir(SOURCE)
## files_arr is numpy array object
files_arr =  np.array(os.listdir(SOURCE))
```

### Custom function to check the file size

Make sure the file is not folder using `os.path.isfile()`

```
def check_file_size(file_name):
    file_abs_path = os.path.join(SOURCE,file_name)
    if os.path.isfile(file_abs_path) and os.path.getsize(file_abs_path) > 0:
        return True
    return False
```

### Filter the array and list using `filter` in-built function. This works on both data types.

```
list(filter(check_file_size, files)) 

list(filter(check_file_size, files_arr))
```

You will be get same result in both.

Comment: your method works but I was looking for vectorized approach using numpy library ...

Comment: What exactly `vectorized` approach here?

Comment: vectorized methods are implemented using numpy library, these methods are more efficient in terms of memory utilization and handling large amount of data. Basically vectorized methods are faster!